# Is it possible to modify interface index

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, driver, network-interface

If the kernel decides to change the interface index for some reason, our userspace code cached interface index does not gets updated and it starts dropping the packet because their is mismatch between interface index cached in userspace and what is actually present in kernel.

I've used if_indextoname(index, interfaceName) to solve this problem. Basically kernel knows which index maps to correct interface name.

**Now comes my requirement:** I need to test my code. Is there a way by which I can simulate index change so that I can verify my code? I have a gut feeling that since index is something which is very much particular to kernel thus it can only be accessed by calls(if_nametoindex()/etc.) but we can't change it. So how do I validate my changeset?

Answer (score 1):

sysctl can't do what you are suggesting.

udev takes care of naming interfaces and even though there are a few naming schemes there is nothing to change the index.

If you can read code have a look here:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#n20

Comment: @Bodgan Are you aware of any other ways by which we can change interface index

Comment: or is it possible at all to modify interface index?

Comment: I suppose you could make a wrapper script to rename the interfaces but I doubt you could change the index of the interfaces.

Manually changing the name of the interface can be done like this: **ip link set enp5s0 name eth1** while the interface is in the down state and of course it wouldn't be hard to make a script to do that.

Comment: @Bodgan I was contemplating that if I bring the interface(the one tied to the node) DOWN via "ip link set <device> down" then can this change the interface index once the interface is UP again. I did this experiment but once I bring the interface down I loose the connectivity(I was logged in to the node via SSH). Since interface went down thus SSH session was also lost. Now to bring it back I can't SSH in. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you can force the netdev to unregister, it will choose a new index when it re-registers. For example if the interface is RNDIS (over USB) you can simply disconnect and reconnect the USB. To make sure the index changed you can add a print in the netdev probe...

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the relevant network module to change ifindex.

Get module name with `basename $(readlink /sys/class/<interface>/device/driver/module)`
then remove and re-insert it like so:

```
modprobe -r <modulename>
modprobe <modulename>
```